# How do I determine k when using k-means clustering? And what's the evaluation criteria of different k？

Tags: algorithm, k-means, unsupervised-learning

I know there is some methods such as: [The Elbow Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elbow_method_(clustering)).

But I don't understand how can you determine which k is better since it's unsupervised learning? What's the evaluation criteria?

Comment: The evaluation methods depends heavily on the software you are using.  A very simple one, though, is whether the clusters are any where near being similar in size.  K-means has a tendency to produce "solar-system" clusters.

Comment: For the Elbow Method you could use the same norm you used for clustering to sum the total error of the clusters to their assigned cluster centers. Find a `k` where `k+1` starts to deliver diminishing increases in accuracy.